# How should I install ROS using CMake, as shown in the tutorials?

Tags: ros, cmake, pythonpath

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ImportError: "from catkin_pkg.package import parse_package" failed: No module named catkin_pkg.package
Make sure that you have installed "catkin_pkg", it is up to date and on the PYTHONPATH.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
execute_process(/usr/local/bin/python
"/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/parse_package_xml.py"
"/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/../package.xml"
"/home/riddhi/catkin_ws/build/catkin/catkin_generated/version/package.cmake")
returned error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package_xml.cmake:63 (safe_execute_process)
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/all.cmake:151 (_catkin_package_xml)
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:20 (include)
CMakeLists.txt:52 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/riddhi/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/riddhi/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263926/i-am-trying-to-install-ros-using-cmake,-as-shown-in-the-tutorials.-i-am-getting-some-strange-errors-in-the-process.-i-also-checked-that-catkin-was-installed-correctly-and-the-python-path-was-also-correct.-can-anybody-please-help-me?/) by [rid7](https://answers.ros.org/users/30774/rid7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-06-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem after some deep learning package installation which messed up my pythonpath
catkin_pkg in my installation was in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages which was missing from pythonpath.
So, this fixed it "export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages"

---

Originally posted by [angeltop](https://answers.ros.org/users/29793/angeltop/) with karma: 351 on 2017-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rid7](https://answers.ros.org/users/30774/rid7/) on 2017-06-15**:
Thanx a lot angeltop! It solved the problem.